# Has the Google Sheets Published URL Suddenly Changed to a Different Format?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Normally, when I use the Google Sheets API, I get a very predictable URL structure from the "Publish Sheet" menu option, that I use to extract the Spreadsheet ID with a regular expression and use it for other tasks on the Google Sheets API.

This has worked for years and is the way that Google's documentation recommends getting the Spreadsheet ID - from the URL.

e.g.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{MYSPREADSHEETID}/pubhtml
```

However, as of today, when publishing a spreadsheet, I now get a URL like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX{BUNCH OF RANDOM CHARACTERS}/pubhtml
```

This breaks my code as the bunch of random characters that appears with 2PAC is not the spreadsheet ID and does not work with the API.

Does anyone know if this is an unannounced change to Google's URL structure or some kind of bug?

Comment: For some reason this is what happens when you choose to "Publish to the Web" your spreadsheet. Tried this on one of my sheets and what happened was the URL was changed like what happened to you. So this applies to all. I think this has something to do with Google's way of handling things. Also know that we are now using the Sheets V4 of the API. You might check the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration) for possible insights.

Comment: Hi, I have noticed the same issue, didn't find an explanation yet. Solution for now is relatively simple: I do not use the URL from the 'publish' popup, but rather from the browser's URL page after the spreadsheet's been published. This page URL contains the spreadsheet ID as before.

Comment: @Alexander - yes, I've done the same thing. Seems a bit rude for Google to do this with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea when or why Google has decided to change their URL structure. The Google Sheets API Documentation states to pull the spreadsheet ID from the editing URL. [Google Sheets API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id)  It seems unlikely to me that this is a bug of some kind, since this has been going on for a while, and to me, seems permanent.

The solution to this problem would be to pull the spreadsheet ID from the editing (or the sharing URL) URL itself instead of using the URL of the published sheet.

I hope Google fixes this issue as this affects consistency across their URLs but for now, the only way to retrieve the spreadsheet ID is to get it from the editing or sharing URLs.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Editing URL and Sharing URL should have the same ID, do you have an example?